# How to render repetitive code based on conditions using react?

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react programming and i would like to know how to render content based on certain conditions sharing same classes.

Below is my code,

```
render = () => {
    const data = this.props.data;

    return <div className="wrapper">
        {this.data.status === 'ready' && this.state.missing &&
            <div className="unknown">
                <div className="status missing">content1</div>
            </div>
        }
        {this.data.status === 'incomplete' &&
            <div className="unknown">
                <div className="status incomplete">content2</div>
            </div>
        }
        {this.data.status === 'failed' &&
            <div className="unknown">
                <div className="status failed">content 3</div>
            </div>
        }
    }
```

How can i refactor the above code. i feel it is repetitive. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Assign values that will be different, e.g: `className` to variables, then use these variables in your markup: `<div className={statusClassVariable} ...`.

If you separate the repetitive markup into a component, the variables/props you need to achieve this should become clear.

Comment: Agree, but your example doesn't easily lend itself to refactoring. Where do `condition_x` and `content_x` come from?

Comment: i am using condition_1, condition_2 so on...to represent that the variables are different. updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you elaborate a little more about the conditions? Are you always comparing a certain input (in which case adding a nested `switch` statement could help, or is each condition using new variables?

Assuming your conditions are independent, you could use a generator function for the elements like this:

```
getStatusComponent = (statusClass,content) => {
    return (
        <div className="unknown">
            <div className={'status' + statusClass}>{content}</div>
        </div>
     )
}

render = () => {
const data = this.props.data;

return <div className="wrapper">
    {condition_1 && condition_2 && getStatusComponent('missing',content1)}
    {condition_3 && getStatusComponent('incomplete',content2)}
    {condition_4 && getStatusComponent('failed',content3)}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't too bad IMO. The pattern is fairly common. You might consolidate the div.unknown that all the cases share.

```
render = () => {
const data = this.props.data;

return <div className="wrapper">
    <div className="unknown">
        {condition_1 && condition_2 &&
            <div className="status missing">content1</div>
        }
        {condition_3 &&
            <div className="status incomplete">content2</div>
        }
        {condition_4 &&
            <div className="status failed">content 3</div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

If content1 and content2 etc. are really verbose and you don't want that, you might consider seeing how much markup they share, and simply swapping out certain parts of it. In other words, move your conditional checks as far down the tree as possible.

```
const getClassname = (condition_1, condition_2, condition_3, condition_4) => {
    if (condition_1 && condition_2) { return 'status missing' }
    if (condition_3) { return 'status incomplete' }
    if (condition_4) { return 'status failed' }
    return null;
}


render = () => {
const data = this.props.data;
return <div className="wrapper">
    <div className="unknown">
        <div className={getClassname(condition_1, condition_2, condition_3, condition_4)}>
            content {/*you now need to decide how to generate content. You can make a `getContent` function, or perhaps do more swapping on a case-by-case basis. It depends on your content*/}
        </div>
    </div>
}
```